# Weblogic Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, struts2, weblogic12c

I am getting this exception when deploying code on Weblogic server. Same WAR file is running fine on tomcat and Jboss. It seems like incompatible versions of spring jars but i am not able to find any such inside my app. 
I Checked with dependencies Hierarchy in eclipse, but no any conflicting or lower version of Spring jar found.

Here is my POM file dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>




   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-pdfa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6-1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6</version>
</dependency>





<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-digester/commons-digester -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>



 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- slf4j-bridge for commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>  
        <version>1.7.1</version>  
    </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>

</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-spring-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-dojo-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-java8-support-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-java8-support-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-chain/commons-chain -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-chain</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-chain</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.4</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jconfig/jconfig -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jconfig</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconfig</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>crimson</groupId>
<artifactId>crimson</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>

</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jblas/jblas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jblas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jblas</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung-graph-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.b2</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12</version>
</dependency>






<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eclipse/jdtcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kennycason/kumo -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kennycason</groupId>
    <artifactId>kumo</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.1</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-buffer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.47.Final</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.47.Final</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.47.Final</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-handler -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.47.Final</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.47.Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/d3js -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>d3js</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6</version>
</dependency>


 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache/lucene-stemmers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-stemmers</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jcommon -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.olap4j/olap4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
<dependency> 
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId> 
<version>4.0</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jettison-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc6 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>

</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opensymphony/xwork -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.resource/connector-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xbean/xbean-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</exclusion>

<exclusion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.4</version>

        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.4</version>
            <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>



  </dependencies>
```

Comment: There is not enough context here, you need to provide your stacktrace if this is going to make sense. Use the maven dependency plugin rather than looking at dependencies in eclipse, i.e. "mvn dependency:tree" from the command line. If this is running fine on other application servers then this is most likely a conflict in classpath between your application and WebLogic's own dependencies.

Comment: Weblogic ships with it is own Spring library. Configure your app to use the application spring version (application first class loading) instead of considering the app servers firsts.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please help me by providing any relevant link.. I am not sure how to do it on weblogic.

Comment: How about reading the weblogic documentation? But here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350631/override-spring-jar-in-weblogic-12c is a post explaining what to do.

Comment: Already tried with this one.. But it did n't worked for me.